# Websphere MQ as a data source for Apache Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-mq, spark-streaming

I was digging into the possibilities for Websphere MQ as a data source for spark-streaming becuase it is needed in one of our use case.
I got to know that [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) is the protocol that supports the communication from MQ data structures but since I am a newbie to spark streaming I need some working examples for the same. 
Did anyone try to connect the MQ with spark streaming. Please devise the best way for doing so.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic since it doesn't fit Stack Overflow's question guidelines. I'd suggest asking these broad architecture and feasibility questions at http://mqseries.net or one of the other online MQ forums.

Comment: I think it may just be a phrasing problem. Instead of the vague _"I was looking into this thing. What's the best solution?"_ you could ask a direct question. _"How do I read data from Websphere MQ via Apache Spark?"_ If you know more about the Websphere MQ side of the question you could add more information about that. Does it support SQL? How do you normally query it? What clients exist for it? Then someone who know Spark can probably help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I am posting here the working code for CustomMQReceiver which connects the Websphere MQ and reads data :

```
public class CustomMQReciever extends Receiver<String> { String host = null;
int port = -1;
String qm=null;
String qn=null;
String channel=null;
transient Gson gson=new Gson();
transient MQQueueConnection qCon= null;

Enumeration enumeration =null;

public CustomMQReciever(String host , int port, String qm, String channel, String qn) {
    super(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_2());
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.qm=qm;
    this.qn=qn;
    this.channel=channel;

}

public void onStart() {
    // Start the thread that receives data over a connection
    new Thread()  {
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                initConnection();
                receive();
            }
            catch (JMSException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
public void onStop() {
    // There is nothing much to do as the thread calling receive()
    // is designed to stop by itself isStopped() returns false
}

 /** Create a MQ connection and receive data until receiver is stopped */
private void receive() {
  System.out.print("Started receiving messages from MQ");

    try {

    JMSMessage receivedMessage= null;

        while (!isStopped() && enumeration.hasMoreElements() )
        {

            receivedMessage= (JMSMessage) enumeration.nextElement();
            String userInput = convertStreamToString(receivedMessage);
            //System.out.println("Received data :'" + userInput + "'");
            store(userInput);
        }

        // Restart in an attempt to connect again when server is active again
        //restart("Trying to connect again");

        stop("No More Messages To read !");
        qCon.close();
        System.out.println("Queue Connection is Closed");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        restart("Trying to connect again");
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        // restart if there is any other error
        restart("Error receiving data", t);
    }
    }

  public void initConnection() throws JMSException
{
    MQQueueConnectionFactory conFactory= new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    conFactory.setHostName(host);
    conFactory.setPort(port);
    conFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
    conFactory.setQueueManager(qm);
    conFactory.setChannel(channel);


    qCon= (MQQueueConnection) conFactory.createQueueConnection();
    MQQueueSession qSession=(MQQueueSession) qCon.createQueueSession(false, 1);
    MQQueue queue=(MQQueue) qSession.createQueue(qn);
    MQQueueBrowser browser = (MQQueueBrowser) qSession.createBrowser(queue);
    qCon.start();

    enumeration= browser.getEnumeration();
   }

 @Override
public StorageLevel storageLevel() {
    return StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_2();
}
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the same, but only one executor is consuming the message as of now. Do you know any approach to have multiple executors consumes messages in parallel ? And also how you manage the failure scenarios? If the streaming app stops intermittently, whats the approach you have not to lose the messages?

Comment: @sparker I think in the receiver based approach you have one receiver and then create multiple executors to process the received data parallelly. If you want the true degree of parallelism, then I'd go for Spark+Kafka's receiver-less (direct) approach. Fault handling can be done in spark streaming with the help of regular checkpoints.

Comment: @tom what would be the main method to use the class like?

Comment: @ant0nk you need to instantiate the CustomMQReciever class with the required arguments and then provide this to the Spark-Streaming so that it starts pulling data from there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use JMS to connect to connect Websphere MQ, and Apache Camel can be used to connect to Websphere  MQ.  You can create a custom Receiver like so (note that this pattern could also be used without JMS):

```
class JMSReceiver(topicName: String, cf: String, jndiProviderURL: String)
  extends Receiver[String](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER) with Serializable  {
  //Transient as this will get passed to the Workers from the Driver
  @transient
  var camelContextOption: Option[DefaultCamelContext] = None

  def onStart() = {
    camelContextOption = Some(new DefaultCamelContext())
    val camelContext = camelContextOption.get
    val env = new Properties()
    env.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "???")
    env.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", jndiProviderURL)
    env.setProperty("com.webmethods.jms.clientIDSharing", "true")
    val namingContext = new InitialContext(env);  //using the properties file to create context

    //Lookup Connection Factory
    val connectionFactory = namingContext.lookup(cf).asInstanceOf[javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]
    camelContext.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory))

    val builder = new RouteBuilder() {
        def configure() = {
          from(s"jms://topic:$topicName?jmsMessageType=Object&clientId=$clientId&durableSubscriptionName=${topicName}_SparkDurable&maxConcurrentConsumers=10")
            .process(new Processor() {
            def process(exchange: Exchange) = {
              exchange.getIn.getBody match {
                case s: String => store(s)
              }
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
    builders.foreach(camelContext.addRoutes)
    camelContext.start()
  }

  def onStop() = if(camelContextOption.isDefined) camelContextOption.get.stop()
}
```

You can then create a DStream of your events like so:

```
val myDStream = ssc.receiverStream(new JMSReceiver("MyTopic", "MyContextFactory", "MyJNDI"))
```

Comment: Answer is useful for me but I was looking for Writing Result back to Websphere MQ. Can someone provide solution for it. Thanks

Comment: Hi @DarshanManek - I think you should ask a new question, or search for that answer.  Its pretty different to the receiver part.