# Put Data on Websphere MQ Using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, websphere, spark-streaming, ibm-mq

I have referred below Link to read Data from Websphere MQ using spark streaming . 
    [Websphere MQ as a data source for Apache Spark Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434555/websphere-mq-as-a-data-source-for-apache-spark-streaming).

But I am stuck in writing data back to Websphere MQ from spark streaming .Someone Please provide me some solution for the same.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a framework in apache spark to send message in a JMS queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182427/is-there-a-framework-in-apache-spark-to-send-message-in-a-jms-queue)